# How do I correct my keyboard/mouse pad issues?

Tags: keyboard

Running Ubuntu on HP Pavillion dv7-1243cl.  Keyboard and mouse pad are hypersensitive prone to jumping whereever the curser happens to be.  Curser (pointer) prone to jumping all over the place.  How do I make the keyboard more forgiving and civilized??

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what version of Ubuntu you're running but if you can find settings there will be a section on touchpad/mouse settings that includes sensitivity, have you tried adjusting those?

Comment: The version of Ubuntu is 14.04.  In "system settings" there are adjustments for curser blink and movement speed.  Therste are adjustme ............. There's an example of the problem.  There are adjustments for keyboard repeat speed and something else.  I could find no adjustments for sensitivity.  I believe that the problem is driver related.